# How do I format a Currency value using jstl format tag?

Tags: java, html, jsp, jstl

I have a text box, The value in that text box like 0.0 it is the currency value i need to format it the code is like below

```
 - <div class="input"> <input type="radio" name="minSavingsPre"
   id="minSavingsOn" class="_mirror
   {mirror:{to:'minPlaceholder',autoSubmit:false}}" value="true" />
   <buxwatch:message
   code="fi.admindashboard.rewardcontrols.savingsthresholds.mindollarsavingsofeachreward.radio"
   /> <input type="text" name="minimumSavingPre" id="minimumSavingPre"
   class="_mirror {rules:{required:function(element) {return
   $('#minPlaceholder').val() ==
   'true';}},mirror:{to:'minimumSaving',autoSubmit:false}}" /> </div>
```

I dont know exactly how to format it by using JSTL 
Can any one help me

Answer (score 9):

You could use JSTL tag `<fmt:formatNumber>` for this purpose

**for example:**

```
<p>Currency in USA :
<fmt:setLocale value="en_US"/>
<fmt:formatNumber value="${balance}" type="currency"/></p>
```

**output:** (with balance = `120000.23`)

```
Currency in USA : $120,000.23
```

---

**See**

- [`<fmt:formatNumber>` doc](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_format_formatnumber_tag.htm)

Comment: i need to format the above text box  in that  the value currency 0.0 comes from the below code {return
   $('#minPlaceholder').val() ==
   'true';} how can i format it